# Is it possible to detect touches of a button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an app and i want to detect touches on a button like first touch, second touch. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes.  Next question.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it..

```
UIButton *sampleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[sampleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 52)];
[sampleButton setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sampleButton setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
[sampleButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"redButton.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:sampleButton];
```

Then in the method buttonPressed you can tally up the touches

```
-(void)buttonPressed
{
   touchCount++;
   // Do something or not
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just count the touch events in a variable.

Comment: I think the OP might have wanted a bit more help than this.